# Help with the proof of the converse of the geometric theorem of isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry

Here is the direct theorem: [proof of isosceles triangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419025/proof-of-isosceles-triangle)

Is posible to prove the reciprocal of that theorem that it's:

> In one triangle with two congruent angles it oppossed two  congruent sides.

I know a proof but it uses the fact that the sum of the measure of the angles of any triangle is equal to 180° and using the criteria Angle-Side-Angle: just bisect the remaining angle, and apply that result in both triangle.

But I'm not very happy with that, there exist another proof "more elementary"?

Comment: You could prove it using the law of sines. I guess you'd have to be happy with a proof for the law of sines, for which there are direct proofs: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Law_of_Sines

Comment: @DreiCleaner It seems to work that way, just only for the thing that I'm not sure how "elemetary" is the definition of the Trig. functions.  I will be happy with a pure geometric proof rather than analytical way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a triangle $\triangle(AA'C)$ with equal angles  at $A$ and $A'$. Then $\triangle(AA'C)$ is congruent to $\triangle(A'AC)$ because the angles at $A$ and $A'$ are equal, and $|AA'|=|A'A|$. It follows that $|AC|=|A'C|$.

Comment: I think this is correct, it reminds me the proof of pappus of the direct theorem.

Comment: Yes, I'm happy with that. It only requires the criterion of Angle-Side-Angle and a lot of cleverness. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found this: [https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI6.html](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI6.html)
it seems that it is that I was looking for, but... it uses the contradiction method, do you know any direct proof?

Answer (score 0):

Option:

Consider angle bisector at $C$ in

$\triangle AA'C$ .

It intersects base $\overline{AA'}$ in $B$.

$\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle A'CB$ are congruent by $SAA$.

(Side $CB$, angle $C/2$, and $A=A'$)