# is still there a contradiction in the proof by contradiction of the proposition 6 of Elements using this triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

The proposition 6 says:

> If in a triangle two angles equal one another, then the sides opposite the equal angles also equal one another.

And the [proof](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI6.html) of Euclid in his Elements basically is (for detailed proof visit the link):  Let's assume the sides opposite are not equal, then this allows us to construct a congruent triangle with the initial triangle (by the SAS criterion)  **inside** of the initial triangle, but is not **overlapping** and this is absurd because **the whole is greater than the part** (Common notion 5).  So there must be a contradiction assuming that in a triangle the sides opposite of congruent angles are not equal, thus they must be equals as requiered.

But imagine this Triangle △ABC where the ∡A = ∡B = 0
[image: Triangle ABC]

Following Euclid construction we obtain the congruent (by SAS) **inside** triangle △ABD with △ABC :
[image: Triangle ABD]

But this time both triangles do **overlap** completely.

Maybe I'm not completely 'formal' with the use of overlap but what else is supposed to mean in the contradiction of Euclid?

This is the first proof by contradiction given in the Elements and I do not have any against this method in general, but in this case it seems is not enough because it relies in what you can see in the diagram, and this could be very tricky, often they (the diagrams) have implicit/hidden hypothesis that you work with but they are not mentioned in the original statement.

And personally if the case is that the contradiction is you can 'see' that in the two congruent triangles one is smaller than the other,  why he previously gave such a [complicated construction](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI2.html) in an earlier proposition just for copy one segment in another position? Yes, I know because to avoid "implicit hypothesis" like motion in the figures, and that's perfect but why soften the methods later? also in previous [Prop. 5](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI5.html), he gave again such a complicated construction (well known as the *Pons Asinorum*) that he perfectly could have simplified but he rather choose the "more formal" one.

This proof in my opinion is out of the spirit of his work. Or maybe I'm not understanding his reasoning correctly.

Comment: That figure is not a triangle.  In some situations it may make sense to treat it as a "degenerate" triangle, but lots of things go wrong if you treat it as a proper triangle.  For instance, any point on the segment $\overline {AB}$  could equally well be the third vertex.  There is no analog of that for a general triangle.

Comment: Is not a triangle defined by Euclid as a figure with three sides each side being a segment? "Definition 20 of Elements: Of trilateral figures, an equilateral triangle is that which has its three sides equal, an isosceles triangle that which has two of its sides alone equal, and a scalene triangle that which has its three sides unequal. "

Comment: As you remark, many properties of triangles fail for degenerate ones.  Perhaps that's an ambiguity in Euclid, I don't recall.  But even basic congruence...Presumably the two triangles $\Delta ACB$ and $\Delta AC'B$, where $C'$ is some other point on the segment $AB$ should be congruent, since you can superimpose one on the other.  But the sides are not even in proportion so, while they may be similar in that the angles are the same, they fail that basic property of similar triangles.

Comment: [Definition $19$](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/defI19.html) rather unhelpfully speaks of trilateral figures of the plain, figures bound by $3$ line segments.  To be sure, "figure" is not defined anywhere, but there we are.  I believe that's as close to a definition of a triangle as you'll find in The Elements.

Comment: @lulu Yes I agree with you if $C'$ it is an arbitrary point.  But in this case is not. Superimpose should not be enough to proof the congruence of two triangles, that's why Euclid give the congruence of triangle criterions (although he did not use this term) you should do it with a valid criterion like SAS. But I'm aware that it is possible to proof such triangles are congruent with the ASA criterion, in that case I rather would suspect from the ASA criterion that of the "one line triangle".

Comment: But of course Euclid proves SAS by invoking superposition (a concept he never formally introduces).  Not sure what you are after here...it has long been noted that the Elements do not actually provide a solid axiomatic basis for Geometry, as evidenced by the fact that Euclid goes outside the axioms to prove various results.  Hilbert famously revised the axiom set to "patch up" the gaps in Euclid.  It's remarkable (astonishing really) how strong Euclid is despite these gaps.

Comment: @lulu I see, that's very interesting. That's why I'm after here, I want to know the point of view of other people in my study of Euclidean Geometry. Specifically in this case I did not convince me the Euclid proof when there is another more elegant like the answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799983/help-with-the-proof-of-the-converse-of-the-geometric-theorem-of-isosceles-triang/3800029#3800029

Comment: Well, there are many arguments in Euclid that have been simplified over the centuries.  Millenia, really.  The proof of the Pythagorean Theorem in particular...personally, I am quite fond of the [one in Euclid](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI47.html), but it is very, very far from the easiest to understand.

Comment: Though that proof use the ASA...

Comment: @lulu Yes, for me is more easy to follow the generalization of that theorem made by Pappus than the classic proof of Euclid.  Anyway, thank you for your help.